# List With Multiple Types

Tags: c#, .net

In C#, Is there a way to create a `list` that holds multiple types? My list items can be `int`, `string`, `DateTime`, or `char`. I'm aware of the use of `List<object>` or `ArrayList` but those are not good practice because of the encapsulation. Is there a good approach to achieve that? I thought that creating an interface might be helpful but I couldn't figure out a way.

Comment: Yes there is. It's called List<Object>!  I'd question why you want to do that though.

Comment: You know the solution and you know it's bad. That should be an indication that idea is wrong and make you want to find an alternative solution, *not* a workaround.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need this? A bit of back story may offer a better solution..

Comment: I wish to create a method that takes TableNameString, and a list of <ColumnNameString, Value>. That method should insert a new record in TableName (database) depending on the columns/values provided by the list. Obviously values can be of many types

Comment: What you could do is create an interface IDoDatabaseStuff with multiple concrete implementations of the interface for each value set. You would have something higher up in the chain determining which implementation to call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with a second but distinct approach (may be described in other answer but now implemented here) to this, this time leveraging implicit operations, and also with the ability to use the framework List type:

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new List<Item>
    {
        1,
        "foo",
        DateTime.Now,
        'x'
    };
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (item.ToString());
    }
    int i = list[0];
    string s = list[1];
    DateTime dt = list[2];
    char c = list[3];
    Console.WriteLine ("int: {0}, string: {1}, DateTime: {2}, char: {3}", i, s, dt, c);
}

enum Kind
{
    Int,
    String,
    DateTime,
    Char
}

class Item
{
    int intValue;
    string stringValue;
    DateTime dateTimeValue;
    char charValue;
    Kind kind;

    public object Value
    {
        get
        {
            switch (kind)
            {           
                case Kind.Int:
                    return intValue;
                case Kind.String:
                    return stringValue;
                case Kind.DateTime:
                    return dateTimeValue;
                case Kind.Char:
                    return charValue;
                default:
                    return null;
            }

        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {   
        return Value.ToString();
    }

    // Implicit construction
    public static implicit operator Item(int i)
    {
        return new Item { intValue = i, kind = Kind.Int };
    }
    public static implicit operator Item(string s)
    {
        return new Item { stringValue = s, kind = Kind.String };
    }
    public static implicit operator Item(DateTime dt)
    {
        return new Item { dateTimeValue = dt, kind = Kind.DateTime };
    }
    public static implicit operator Item(char c)
    {
        return new Item { charValue = c, kind = Kind.Char };
    }

    // Implicit value reference
    public static implicit operator int(Item item)
    {
        if(item.kind != Kind.Int) // Optionally, you could validate the usage
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException("Trying to use a " + item.kind + " as an int");
        }
        return item.intValue;
    }
    public static implicit operator string(Item item)
    {
        return item.stringValue;
    }
    public static implicit operator DateTime(Item item)
    {
        return item.dateTimeValue;
    }
    public static implicit operator char(Item item)
    {
        return item.charValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is better than `IConvertable` because there is nothing going under the hood. Performance is guaranteed to be almost maximal hear. I changed my accepted answer for that reason only. Thanks Aaron.

Comment: I'm planning on marking `intValue`, `stringValue`, `dateTimeValue`, `charValue`, and `kind` as `private` leaving only the `Value` property. However, in order to make the answer best, is there a way to return the `Value` by default when the instance is accessed? Otherwise, `IConvertable` would still be superior from this point of view.

Comment: I made the change.  have fun :)

Answer (score 2):

Like the other poster said, in your case I think `List<object>` is probably fine, but I decided to see if I could come up with something/anything so here's a "non-real-world" (i.e. there's no good reason to do this so please don't paste it into your production code) example for you:

```
void Main()
{
    var items = new Items();
    items.Add(1);
    items.Add("foo");
    items.Add(DateTime.Now);
    items.Add('x');

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (item);
    }
}

enum Kind
{
    Int,
    String,
    DateTime,
    Char
}

class Items : IEnumerable<object>
{
    Stack<int> Ints = new Stack<int>();
    Stack<string> Strings = new Stack<string>();
    Stack<DateTime> DateTimes = new Stack<DateTime>();
    Stack<char> Chars = new Stack<char>();
    List<Kind> Kinds = new List<Kind>();

    IEnumerator<object> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var kind in Kinds)
        {
            switch (kind)
            {
                case Kind.Int:
                    yield return Ints.Pop();
                    break;
                case Kind.String:
                    yield return Strings.Pop();
                    break;
                case Kind.DateTime:
                    yield return DateTimes.Pop();
                    break;
                case Kind.Char:
                    yield return Chars.Pop();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (this as System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>).GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(int i)
    {
        Ints.Push(i);
        Kinds.Add(Kind.Int);
    }

    public void Add(string s)
    {
        Strings.Push(s);
        Kinds.Add(Kind.String);
    }

    public void Add(DateTime dt)
    {
        DateTimes.Push(dt);
        Kinds.Add(Kind.DateTime);
    }

    public void Add(char c)
    {
        Chars.Push(c);
        Kinds.Add(Kind.Char);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best choice is either make a `List<object>` and cast it every time or make a wrapper like this:

```
class Either<TRight, TLeft> 
{
    private TLeft Left {get; private set;}
    private TRight Right {get; private set;}
    private bool IsLeft {get; private set;}        
}
```

I didn't add the constructors or anything else needed, I hope that's straight forward enough. I got the idea from F# and functional languages, you can check that later if you want to improve it.

Then make a `List<Either<DateTime,char>>` and ask in every case if it's a `DateTime` or `char` and work your way around that

Answer (score 1):

`IConvertible`, IIRC, is implemented by all those types, so you could accept a `List<IConvertible>`. Other types implement `IConvertible` as well but not as many as `object` (which is of course almost all types in .NET). This gives you the advantage of using the built-in IConvertible methods to switch between types as desired.

Another easy way is `List<string>` and then just ToString() all of these (IConvertible forces implementation of a culture-specific ToString() overload, and all built-in IConvertibles also override Object.ToString()). You'll take a performance hit as string conversion and parsing is relatively expensive and you'll have to try parsing the string to each primitive before figuring out it's actually just a string, so I wouldn't recommend this for large lists that have to be efficiently processed. There's also potential for loss of true type; if you add the string "12345" to the list, the parser will think it was originally an int, though what you passed was only ever a string.

I think a wrapper is your best bet. The best built-in one is Tuple; you could define a `List<Tuple<int,string,DateTime,char,int>>` where the last `int` parameter identifies the populated field of the Tuple (1=int, 2=string, etc), and all others will have their default value. You can use Item5 to dynamically retrieve Item1 through Item4, or just put it in a switch statement. You can wrap the list and all this tuple packing and unpacking in extension methods operating on the list, or by deriving or containing the list in another class.

As a hybrid of the previous two approaches, you can encapsulate the type information and the string representation: `Tuple<string, ElementType>` (where ElementType is an enum representing possible types the string representation originally could have been) which eliminates the guesswork; just parse back to the type specified.

Comment: Thanks @KeithS, The `List<IConvertible>` approach is perfect for me because it seamlessly accepts all my types (they happen to be the four I indicated in the question). But, just to double check, do you know if the `IConvertible` approach suffer from some hidden boxing or encapsulation? (If so, the approach will not be that great because its performance would be similar to `List<object>`).

For those who want to make a list of their own classes, the `List<Tuple<int,string,DateTime,char,int>>` approach is perfect except that I would replace the fourth tuple (`int`) with an `enum`
Max comment :)

Comment: AFAIK, there's very little boxing. The IConvertible implementation differs for each IConvertible type (because of course the process differs) but most IConvertibles are number-based with one notable exception (string) so the conversions usually just involve an explicit cast of the number to the requested type. It's a bit more complex for String, DateTime and a couple others but there should be no need for boxing.