# Multiple-type arrays in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

Lots of programming languages support arrays with multiple types inside one array, like javascript:

```
let myArray = ["foo", "bar", 123, true, new MyCustomObject()];
```

Or python:

```
myArray = ["foo", "bar", 123, True, new MyCustomObject()];
```

But in C#, you have to specify the type of item that is in the array. So if you put in more than one type of item, such as `"foo"` and `123` and `true` in the same array, it throws an error. Is there a work-around to this?

Comment: Use `object` as type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List With Multiple Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494850/list-with-multiple-types)

Comment: However, I'm not sure _why_ you would want to do this. C# is strongly typed for a reason. In my opinion, it's a detriment that other languages allow you to have arrays with mixed types. At least use inheritance or an interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# does allow anonymous objects

```
var myThing = new { "foo", "bar", 123, True, new MyCustomObject() };
```

Or if you prefer, a collection:

```
var myThings = new List<object>{"foo", "bar", 123, True, new MyCustomObject()};
```

But really, I question why you would want to.

Far better to have a fully defined type:

```
 class MyThing
 {
     public string FirstName {get;init};
     public string LastName {get;init;}
     public int Age {get;init;}
     public bool IsMale {get;init;}
     public MyCustomObject Custom {get;init;}
 }

 var myThing = new MyThing
 {
     FirstName = "Foo",
     LastName = "bar",
     Age = 39,
     IsMale = true,
     Custom = new MyCustomObject(),
  };
```

Comment: Note on the anonymous object, you need to specify the property names.